# Bijective function with certain properties

Tags: probability

I'm looking for a function, or family of functions having certain properties (if it exists), and I do not know how to look for it in the mathematical literature.

A valid answer to this question would be either a way to search for this kind of things myself, or the function itself if you have an idea.

Here are the properties it should have :

- definition domain : $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, n>1$
- $f$ should be tractable and bijective, with $f^{-1}$ tractable
- $f$ should be differentiable with respect to all its inputs, and its derivative should be tractable
- and last but not least, if $X$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^n$ with a density function $d_X$, the density $d_Y$ of $Y = f(X)$ should be tractable. According to Wikipedia, it is defined by :
  $$d_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb R^n}d_X(x)\delta(y-f(X))dx$$
  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Note : by "tractable" I mean that I need to have an expression allowing me to find its value.

EDIT : ANSWER :
Such a fonction does not exist because 1) and 3) are not compatible (see comment from Qiaochu Yuan)

Comment: What is an "expression"  and how can it allow you to do anything? Can it also stop you from doing something?

Comment: The first three properties are already impossible to satisfy simultaneously, and depending on what you mean by “tractable” maybe the first two. A bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can’t be continuous with continuous inverse, nor can it be differentiable (anywhere).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Fascinating comment.  Please consider that I (who am not the OP) am **totally ignorant** here.  Any easy to read online source(s) that relate to your comment?  If relevant, I've survived volume 1 of Apostol's Calculus - 2nd Ed, and chapters 1,2 of Palka's Complex Function Theory.

Comment: @user2661923: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain (for the continuous version). For the differentiable version it seems I spoke a little too hastily; we need enough differentiability to apply Sard's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) and then the implicit function theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thanks a lot for the links and answer, that helped a lot ! I won't lie to you, I'm a little bit sad that it cannot exist though, but it makes sense.

Comment: You may be surrenduring too easily.  According to Qiaochu Yuan's first link, the result is due to L. E. J. Brouwer, circa 1912.  So, if you go back in time to 1911 and kill L. E. J. Brouwer, then come back to today, perhaps it could exist.